# iTunes asks me to "setup" iPod - Which has already been setup and has songs on it. Will they be removed?

Tags: sync, music, ipod

I setup my iPod on a friends computer and copied a whole bunch of songs onto it. Today, I install iTunes onto my home computer and plugged in my iPod. It asked me to set it up...

If I click "yes" to the setup, will it remove all my songs and start syncing from "My Music" folder? Or will it give me the option to not do that? I don't want to plug in my iPod and have iTunes remove all my songs :/

Both computers are running Windows - If that matters.
Seems like a stupid question, but it also seems like something an Apple product would do xD

Answer (score 1):

What will happen when you connect the iPod depends on the settings of iTunes.

From [Overview of syncing iPhone or iPod touch with your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386):

> This article gives an overview of how
>   to set up iPhone or iPod touch to sync
>   with your computer, and where to get
>   additional information.
>
> When you connect iPhone or iPod touch
>   to your computer, items are
>   automatically synced according to your
>   preferences set in iTunes.
>
> You only need to set which items are
>   synced in iTunes on your computer
>   once. After that, just connect iPhone
>   or iPod touch to start a sync.
>
> Contacts, calendars, notes, and
>   bookmarks are synced from (or to) your
>   computer, so if you add, change, or
>   delete them on iPhone or iPod touch,
>   they are changed on your computer, and
>   vice versa. You can also sync contacts
>   with your Yahoo! or Google Address
>   Book.
>
> Email account settings (on iPhone
>   only), music, movies, TV shows,
>   podcasts, and photos are synced
>   one-way, from your computer to iPhone
>   (though you can import photos taken
>   with iPhone to your computer).
>
> **If you like, you can set iPhone or iPod touch to sync with only a portion of what's on your computer**. For
>   example, you might want to sync only a
>   group of contacts from your address
>   book, or you may want to sync only
>   songs from certain playlists so you
>   don't fill up iPhone or iPod touch
>   with all your music.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your iPod with multiple computers as long as it's set to **Manually manage music**.

Have a look at [this Apple Knowledgebase Entry](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1202) for more detail.